# React component styles depend on its parent

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Sorry if the question is stupid, I'm new to React.

Let's say I have such a component:

```
import React from 'react';

import Container from '../Miscellaneous/Container/Container'
import MaskedImgBlock from '../MaskedImgBlock/MaskedImgBlock'

import HeaderImg from 'assets/img/header/header-img.jpg'

import styles from './Header.module.scss'

const header = (props) => {

  return(
    <header className={styles.mainHeader}>
      <Container>
        <div className={styles.mainHeader_inner}>

          ... {/* some other code here */}

          <MaskedImgBlock 
            src={HeaderImg}
            alt="Team members photo"/>

        </div>
      </Container>
    </header>
  )
};

export default header;
```

And I have in it a reusable `MaskedImgBlock` component:

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './MaskedImgBlock.module.scss'

const maskedImgBlock = ({ src, alt }) => {

  return (
    <div className={styles.imgBlock}>
      <div className={styles.imgBlock_clipped}>
        <img className={styles.imgBlock_img}
             src={src}
             alt={alt} />
      </div>
    </div>
)};

export default maskedImgBlock;
```

This `MaskedImgBlock` component I want to use inside multiple components in my app, and it must keep its structure and most of styles, but some styles of it's inner elements must be changed according to the component's position.

For example, when this component is inside `Header` component, one of its inner divs must have a green background-color, and if it's inside a footer component, other inner div must be of yellow background color.

How can I achieve this effect in the most nice way?

Comment: When you're talking about "inner elements" you're talking about both `div`s that wrap the `img` element inside `MaskedImgBlock`?

Comment: yep, and the `img` tag itself. In my App I need to apply different CSS masks to the img inside `MaskedImgBlock` (depending on its position), and some other properties to adjust these masks, also some `div`s properties will be changed according to the  `MaskedImgBlock` position

Comment: You could pass a className as a prop to the `MaskedImgBlock` component and pass a different className as the prop depending where you call the component.

Comment: @MathisWitte yep, I could, but if I have like 10 different versions of this block I will apply all these versions styles in `MaskedImgBlock` stylesheet, and I want (I hope it's possible) to apply somehow these versions styles in the parents' styles files. Like in the `Header` stylesheet in this example (cause these unique styles are relevant only if `MaskedImgBlock` is the child of `Header` block)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly to what's done in the `Material-UI` framework for `React`, you could introduce a new `prop` for the `MaskedImgBlock` component, like in the following example:

```js
const MaskedImgBlock = ({
  src,
  alt,
  classes = {}
}) => {
  const {
    root = '',
    imgWrapper = '',
    img = '',
  } = classes 
  return (
    <div className={`${styles.imgBlock} ${root}`}
      <div className={`${styles.imgBlock_clipped} ${imgWrapper}`>
        <img className={`${styles.imgBlock_img} ${img}`}></igm>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then, assuming you want to style `root` and `img`, you could do the following:

```js
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Container>
        <div>
          <MaskedImgBlock 
            src={HeaderImg}
            alt="Team members photo"
            classes={{ 
              root: styles.mainHeader_maskedImgBlock_root,
              img: styles.mainHeader_maskedImgBlock_img
            }}
          />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Or, if you just want the default styling, you don't pass any extra `props` to your component:

```js
const Header = (props) => {
  return (
    <header>
      <Container>
        <div>
          <MaskedImgBlock 
            src={HeaderImg}
            alt="Team members photo"
          />
        </div>
      </Container>
    </header>
  )
}
```

This way, you only pass the classes that you want and everything else will default to existing styles.

Answer (score 1):

How do you define styles for `MaskedImgBlock` classes in parent components?

You use css modules in `MaskedImgBlock`, so its class names will be generated according with your style/css/or*other-loader config.

If you need couple different representation - it better to add some prop to `MaskedImgBlock` component and path it from parent like

```
import React from 'react';

import Container from '../Miscellaneous/Container/Container'
import MaskedImgBlock from '../MaskedImgBlock/MaskedImgBlock'

import HeaderImg from 'assets/img/header/header-img.jpg'

import styles from './Header.module.scss'

const header = (props) => {

  return(
    <header className={styles.mainHeader}>
      <Container>
        <div className={styles.mainHeader_inner}>

          ... {/* some other code here */}

          <MaskedImgBlock 
            theme={'green'}
            src={HeaderImg}
            alt="Team members photo"/>

        </div>
      </Container>
    </header>
  )
};

export default header;
```

If you want to customize your `MaskedImgBlock` component with many styles from different parent compoments -  the best approach is adding className (or etc.) prop to your `MaskedImgBlock` component, where you can pass class name from parent component (like your Header component).

```
import React from 'react';

import Container from '../Miscellaneous/Container/Container'
import MaskedImgBlock from '../MaskedImgBlock/MaskedImgBlock'

import HeaderImg from 'assets/img/header/header-img.jpg'

import styles from './Header.module.scss'

const header = (props) => {

  return(
    <header className={styles.mainHeader}>
      <Container>
        <div className={styles.mainHeader_inner}>

          ... {/* some other code here */}

          <MaskedImgBlock 
            className={styles.maskedImg}
            src={HeaderImg}
            alt="Team members photo"/>

        </div>
      </Container>
    </header>
  )
};

export default header;
```

And new `MaskedImgBlock`

```
import React from 'react';

import styles from './MaskedImgBlock.module.scss'

const maskedImgBlock = ({ src, alt, className = '' }) => {

  return (
    <div className={`${styles.imgBlock} ${className}`}>
      <div className={styles.imgBlock_clipped}>
        <img className={styles.imgBlock_img}
             src={src}
             alt={alt} />
      </div>
    </div>
)};

export default maskedImgBlock;
```